# Please help me understand IOS 7+ icons and Titles

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, release

So their are really two parts to this questions so I am going to break them up.

**Icons:**
So I designed my icon as a vector and exported it in a ridiculously large size. 
[image: App icon]
 Then I put it on the site called "http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/icon_slayer/#.Vdq6BmDbgis" and it generated the icon in all sorts of shapes and sizes.  Then I went to go drag everything into the AppIcon in xcassets and was greeted with TOOONS of boxes, furthermore Xcode wouldn't let me scroll to the right to see the rest of the boxes.  It is just a mess, furthermore instead of asking for specific pixel dimensions it asks for specific pt dimensions.  I am so confused, does it want png's or vectors???  How do I know what size each icon size is supposed to be?

Secondly I want my app to be able to be universal to the point of being played on any device that has sprite kit capabilities.  I noticed that on the sidebar you could select different check boxes for different ios's.  Will just filling out all the boxes for IOS 7 iPad, and IOS 7 iPhone do the trick?

Thirdly I am disappointed by how things turned out.  MY app icon isn't super complicated but when it ends up on an actual device it looks like a anti-aliased mess, yet I see other apps (junk jack x, Monument Valley, Glow hockey, Republique) that have SOOO much more detail then my apps icon yet they look perfect.  How did they achieve this?  BTW to make the app icon I filled out the boxes I could with .pngs.

Fourthly do you think apple will reject this icon because it doesn't follow its design standards?  I am having trouble thinking of a simpler one because this game is just a game, and it doesn't have a logo or anything.

**Titles:**
So I have seen apps that change based on where your looking.  For example i've seen apps where they have one shortened title for when it is on the home screen, and another title for the app store.  SO like on app store "fun game - jump run and play with zippy", but on the home screen "fun game".  How do you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few questions here, I'll try to cover all of them. Let me know if I missed something... :-)

The sizes you need for the icons are actually written in the assets library. I'm attaching an image here:

[image]

You can see that for the iPad App, for example, you need 76pt at 1x and at 2x. That means that you need one .png file at 76x76 pixels and another at 152x152 pixels (76 x 2 = 152). Same logic applies when you see a 3x box (just multiply the number written in pt with the number written next to the x). If you provide the images as .png files with the exact size, that should also take care of the sharpness issue you mentioned.

As for the titles, there are two fields for you app name - one that you set up in XCode and one that you set up on iTunes Connect. The longer name is limited to 256 characters and is displayed on the app store. The shorter one is displayed under the app icon on the device's home screen. That short name should be 11-12 characters long (it can be more, depending on the letters - for example, you can probably fit 16 i's at the same width you would fit only 11 w's). For the short name (bundle display name, on the plist file in XCode), just make sure it doesn't have three dots on the device, because it looks very bad. For the longer name on iTunes Connect, it has to be very similar to the name that's displayed on the device, otherwise, it can get your app rejected. So, for example, if the short name is Game X, the long name can probably be "Game X - A cool multiplayer game" but it can't be "Game Y".

I hope things are clearer now. Good luck!

Comment: Thankyou so much for writing this all up! It makes tons of sense.  One more question.  Does the bundle identifier have to be the same as the title?  And is it supposed to go com.<AppName>.<CompanyName> right?

Comment: And then for <AppName> should that match the app store name, or the home screen name, and does it have to be exact? And then for <CompanyName> should that be the legal name that my iTunes developer account is under, or the name I am releasing the app under?

Comment: Sorry i guess its not much of a thank you if i pepper you with questions.  But when I add an app on iTunes connect, It asks me for the app name, even though it asks for the bundle identifier I made on the site to get my dev testing key.  So which names actually becomes my app name on the app store, the one for the dev key, or the iTunes connect one?

Comment: AppName - up to 256. Will actually be shown on iTunes as the name. BundleIdentifier - recommended to be com.companyName.appName (has to be unique in the app store, so that increases the chances of it actually being unique). CompanyName, in the BundleIdentifier - doesn't have to be the official name. Can be anything you want, just try to keep it consistent.

Comment: And it asks you to provide an app name after already selecting the bundle identifier, because the app name is what's actually displayed to the end user on the AppStore. The bundle id isn't displayed to the user and is meant to be an identifier to your app throughout the App Store (backstage). Good Luck! :-)